# SEO - Landing Pages registration

Tags: seo

I have created 3 Landing Pages. What is the best way to reference them in Google?

1) Save it in my sitemap.xml?
2) created real links in my site that redirect to these pages ? (hidden link ?)

why you prefer one technique over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably put them in sitemap.xml for starters. You should then have appropriate real links to these landing pages with link text that is appropriate for the audience. Hidden links etc sound like 'black hat' SEO techniques which will backfire and get your site penalized.

Each landing page in the site should be differentiated (eg. drug sites with info for doctors and another for patients). If they are just displaying the same content they are not likely to help your SEO ranking efforts.